# Complaint on paper size option

Tags: paper-size

With

```
\documentclass[12pt, B5]{article}
\usepackage[body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
```

why do I get

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [B5].
```

What can I do to remove the warning?

Comment: Simply use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}` to load the paper size within `geometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\the\paperwidth \the\paperheight
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, it had to be `b5paper` also for `\documentclass`.